# Can I simulate ack by using grep with the right combination of options?

Tags: linux, find, grep, xargs, ack

I have ack-grep installed on my local machine, and find it indispensable for quickly 'acking' through a codebase when debugging.

However, on my cheap shared hosting, there is no ack-grep. One of the testimonials on betterthangrep.com mentions a

> Rube Goldberg mess of find/grep/xargs

which sounds like what I need, but coming from the opposite direction.

Does anyone know what it might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual command is named **`ack`**. (Some distributors may have renamed it to `ack-grep` due to name collisions.) The official website is indeed http://betterthangrep.com, and it has a long list of installation methods, even in case your distribution does not have `ack`.

For example, you can download *App::Ack* from Perl's CPAN (using *cpanminus*):

```
cpanm --sudo App::Ack
```

Or get the "standalone" version:

```
curl http://betterthangrep.com/ack-standalone > ~/bin/ack
chmod +x ~/bin/ack
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it manually, and in fact you *should* know how to do it manually. For example, if you've been doing

```
ack function_name --php
```

you can do that (pretty much) as

```
find . -name '*.php' | xargs grep function_name
```

It's longer to type, and you can make an alias or shell script out of it, but it's good to know *how* to do it, just for the sake of knowing how to do it.

Your question makes me smile because usually what I hear is old guard Unix greybeards saying "You don't need `ack`, just use `find`, `xargs` and `grep`."  It's cool to see someone coming at it from the other direction.

Comment: Awfully close to "You don't need that newfangled wheel, just reinvent your own."

Comment: It certainly is, but it's a battle I've stopped getting into.  If people want to do it the old way because That's How Ken And Dennis Say It Should Be, then that's up to them.